# nested grid control not accessible ? Null values ? problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nullreferenceexception

Asp.Net Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_current_report" runat="server" CssClass="grid" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#336699" DataKeyNames="staff_id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="gv_current_report_RowDataBound">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCE4F9" />
  <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" width="30" />
        <asp:Panel ID="detail_grid" runat="server" Style="display: none">
          <asp:GridView ID="gv_detail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="child-grid">
            <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="branch_name" HeaderText="Branch Name" />
              <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="date_contacted" HeaderText="Contacted Date" />
              <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="name" HeaderText="Staff Name" />
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

C# Code

```
protected void gv_current_report_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Int32 staff_id = Convert.ToInt32(gv_current_report.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value);
        db = new ReportsDataContext();
        gv_detail.DataSource = db.tracker_new_report_broker_status_change_current_detail(staff_id);
        gv_detail.DataBind();
    }

}
```

the problem is the panel and the grid view are not accessible in c#? If I create the controls in designer, its accessible but throwing an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Found out the grid view control is **NULL**  in run time.

> ( i.e.) gv_detail=Null

Anyone please shed some light. Any help will be much appreciated!!!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can't access to `gv_detail` just by name, instead you should use something like this: `var mygv_detail = e.Row.FindControl("gv_detail") as GridView;`. same applies to Panel btw.

Comment: Thanks Mate, It worked. You can post that as an answer